# jquery scroll to top convert to scroll to bottom

Tags: jquery, scroll

I copied this code from the internet and wanted the get a identical result, however I want it to scroll down insted. I have tried to convert it as best I could, but I could not get it to work your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // hide #back-top first
    $("#back-top").hide();

    // fade in #back-top
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#back-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#back-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#back-top a').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Maybe you should copy another code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#go-down').click(function () {
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
        return false;
    });​
```

[Update demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wwvxB/2/)

Comment: Thanks so much you are a great help

Comment: @user1656139  If Sibu's answer has helped you, you need to tick it on the left hand side under the arrows to show you have accepted his answer :)